# Fresh installation of Lubuntu 16.04 from a DVD on a MacBook

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, keyboard, 17.10, macbook

I have a MacBook "Core 2 Duo" 2.2 13" (White-SR) 2.2 GHz Core 2 Duo (T7500) with single boot - Ubuntu 17.04 on.

I want to make a fresh installation of Lubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (mac) from a DVD.

I have tried to start the laptop holding the 'c' key down until the DVD drive starts and then release it but no luck. 
I also tried holding the 'option' key down and that gets me to a 'menu' with the only option to start from a hard drive named 'windows' (?) but no DVD drive option. If the hard drive is selected the system does not boot.

**pressing 'esc' during the boot process gets me to the grub menu and/or console. anything i can do from here? **

p.s. I also tried with another .iso CD that I know for sure works 
and did not get any results. 
so probably it's not the specific DVDisc that causes the problem.

thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect a USB keyboard to the Mac.
2. Reboot the Mac and hold the Option key (or Alt key if it's a PC keyboard).

You should then be able to boot from the DVD.

Comment: i do not have a usb keyboard at my disposal at the moment... any other solution? also can you please check my edited question? the native keyboard works when in the grub terminal

Comment: I dint read you correctly, sorry. I'm out if ideas at the moment.